# Pygame keys pressing issues

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to create a small little game for myself in order to practice OOP among other things. However, I noticed that when I press a key it acts as if I've pressed it multiple times. I know now that I can use the event function (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN), I want to figure out what was wrong in what I wrote.

I learned this little loop method in order to create a delay in between key presses if say you were shooting something, and worked properly then. I've compared it to the previous code but I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

```
inDelay = 0

#indent caused because it is in my mainloop
    if inDelay > 0:
        inDelay += 1
    elif inDelay > 6:
        inDelay = 0

#also main loop
    if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) and inDelay == 0:

        if arrowS.x == 163:
            arrowS.x = 413                   
        elif arrowS.x == 413:
            arrowS.x = 663
        elif arrowS.x == 663:
            arrowS.x = 163

    inDelay = 1
```

I can press the key once and have my arrow move to where I want it to just fine, but I don't get a response when I press a second time. I've tried indenting "inDelay = 1" under each movement but that fails also.

Comment: pygame has `pygame.time` which you can use to control time between shoots.  using `indelay` you can get shorter delay on faster computer.

Comment: if something doesn't work then use `print()` to see values in variables (before `if`) - it helps to find where is the problem. You can use `print( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) and inDelay == 0 )` to see if it gives true or false.

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing your while loop.

Comment: @furas thank you, printing the variable showed me that the inDelay just kept adding up forever and never really reached, 0, i just indented it in the "if inDelay > 0" statement and it works now

Comment: now you can put yoru comment as answer and mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
if inDelay > 0:
    inDelay += 1
    if inDelay > 100:
        inDelay = 0
```

This works just how I want it to; the loop seems to be a little impractical though since I need to increase the amount, I'll more than likely use `pygame.time` as was pointed out.

Comment: That first line should probably be `>= 0` otherwise this will only work on the first run through - because once `inDelay` becomes `0`, it will never pass the first clause again.